# How to properly pad and align data in OpenGL for std430 layout

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I cannot get the following structure to work when using it in Shader Storage Object:

Definitions in shader:

```
struct Object
{
    vec4                color;
    mat3                transform;
    float               depth;
    float               pObjIndex;
    //float align1;
    //float align2;
};

layout (std430, binding = 0) buffer Objects
{
  Object objects[];
};
```

It's my understanding that the Object structure is aligned in GLSL by its largest member which is vec4, i.e. by 16-byte boundary. (mat3 is treated as 3-element array of vec3's and is aligned by 12-bytes boundary). The vec4, mat3 and 2 floats give 72 bytes. When I pad the structure to the nearest 16-byte multiple - 80 - with two floats, it's not working properly just as without padding.

Are both variants of this structure's layout - with padding with 2 floats and without any padding - incorrect?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the `mat3` is actually 3 `vec4`s as each vec3 is 3 floats aligned to 16 bytes (or at least it may not straddle a 16 byte boundary)

```
struct Object
{
    float[4]           color;
    float[4][3]         transform;
    float           depth;
    float           pObjIndex;
    //float align1;
    //float align2;
};
```

Comment: "each vec3 is 3 floats aligned to 16 bytes" - Hmm.. Does this correspond with the specification of std430 for  an array of scalars or vectors? : "The size of each element in the array will be the same size of the element type, where **three-component vectors are not rounded up to the size of four-component vectors**. This is also the array’s alignment. The array’s size will
be the element’s size times the number of elements in the array."

Comment: @AlBerger vectors may not straddle a 16 byte boundary so multiple vec3 will end up aligning to 16 byte

Comment: So this structure should be padded with 14 bytes to 96 bytes boundary? How it can be done in GLSL which seems doesn't have one byte data type?

Comment: @AlBerger lets backtrack a bit, color is 4 float aligned to 16, mat3 is 3 vec3, the first is right after color thus aligned to 16 ends at 16+12=28, the second can't fit in the remaining space so jumps to the next 16 byte boundary (32) and the same for the last one => 16+16*2+12=60 and then add 2 floats = 68 pad to 16 byte multiple means 3 padding floats and final size is 80

Comment: The `vec3` alignment rules are such that it ***begins*** on a 4N boundary (where N is the machine unit size, 4-bytes in this case). That implicitly guarantees that it will not straddle a 16-byte boundary, but the underlying rule is actually regarding where it ***starts***, rather than ends. That is why you can safely pack a single `float` after a `vec3` without breaking alignment.